# AJAX Request - Also Clear Placeholder text as well as HTML input field value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a select menu that, when a user makes a selection, it fires off an AJAX request to a PHP script to query a database and return a value that matches the selection and inserts this into an associated input field. If there is no matching value returned it clears out the associated input field.

This is all working well, but I've just realised that the default placeholder text appears when there is no matching value as the input field is empty. I need to clear the placeholder text at the same time I clear the input field but haven't figured out a way to do this so far.

Here's the AJAX code that calls the PHP script and updates the input field:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#smsFromName").change(function() {
    var smsFromName = $("#smsFromName").val();
    console.log(smsFromName);
    $.post('getSMSSender.php', {
      senderName: smsFromName
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        alert("error");
        $("#smsFrom").html('');
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else if (data[0] && data[0].senderMobile) {
        console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
        $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
      } else {
        console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
        $("#smsFrom").val("");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      $("#smsFrom").html('');
    });
  });
});
```

and here's the HTML input field:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control w48" name="smsFrom" id="smsFrom" placeholder="0412 345 678" value="0417 555 666">
```

I'm hoping I can simply add some code after:

```
$("#smsFrom").val("");
```

to also clear out the placeholder text but I'm stumped as to how to do that?

Comment: Why? The placeholder text is still applicable, surely?

Comment: If you really **must** clear out the placeholder text, and it's a standard placeholder set via the placeholder attribute, try `$("#smsFrom").attr('placeholder', '').html("");`

Comment: @Quentin the placeholder text is the default value that gets loaded dynamically when the page loads and is incorrect once a different selection has been made. I see what you're saying though - I might need to change the placeholder text to a more generic value if I can't update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### VanillaJS

You can easily use vannila.js here...

```
document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "";
```

So it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#smsFromName").change(function() {
    var smsFromName = $("#smsFromName").val();
    console.log(smsFromName);
    $.post('getSMSSender.php', {
      senderName: smsFromName
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        alert("error");
        $("#smsFrom").html('');
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else if (data[0] && data[0].senderMobile) {
        console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
        $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
      } else {
        console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
        $("#smsFrom").val("");
        document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "";
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      $("#smsFrom").html('');
    });
  });
});
```

### jQuery

You could also easily use jQuery here..

```
$("#smsFrom").attr('placeholder', '').html("");
```

So it would result in...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#smsFromName").change(function() {
        var smsFromName = $("#smsFromName").val();
        console.log(smsFromName);
        $.post('getSMSSender.php', {
          senderName: smsFromName
        }, function(data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          if (data.error) {
            alert("error");
            $("#smsFrom").html('');
            return; // stop executing this function any further
          } else if (data[0] && data[0].senderMobile) {
            console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
            $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
          } else {
            console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
            $("#smsFrom").val("");
            $("#smsFrom").attr('placeholder', '').html("");
          }

        }).fail(function(xhr) {
          $("#smsFrom").html('');
        });
      });
    });
```

### Conclusion

Both ways would work. You could use jQuery so it can be of similar type of code, or VanillaJS For Performance. Hope this helped!

Comment: What's the point of mixing jQuery and native DOM API? Either write everything with jQuery or don't use it at all.

Comment: I said the better recommended is the DOM API. Some people may want. That does not deserve a downvote at all @Gothdo

Comment: In such a basic code like this, there isn't any significant difference in performance between DOM API and jQuery. Additionally, if OP uses jQuery in their code, you should as well provide an answer using jQuery. And I can cast votes as I want, don't tell me what deserves a downvote and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you really **need** to change the placeholder text, replace your current statement

> `$("#smsFrom").val("");`

width a chained function to change the placeholder text, like such;

```
 $("#smsFrom").attr('placeholder', '').html("");
```